# Comment out docker-compose block with bash script

Tags: bash, docker, go, docker-compose

I am making a project for local development with dockerized apps. I have 3 different domain on my company that each domain has one docker-compose file with 5 services. (15 projects)

If User of my project wants to deploy only 1 service of their domain or/and 2 of the other domains projects, I have to comment out services in other docker-compose files that dont want to be deployed.

So my question is How can i comment out docker-compose(Go) files block with bash script? I want to choose the lines with their context. For example in below example i want to comment out ap2-php-fpm section. I cant make a work around solution because more projects incoming. I have to intervene go language script with bash script.

Demonstration

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app-php-fpm:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ${src}/
    volumes:
        - $path:path
    networks:
      general-nt:
        aliases:
        - app
    expose:
        - "9000"

  ap2-php-fpm:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ${src}/
    volumes:
        - $path:path
    networks:
      general-nt:
        aliases:
        - app
    expose:
        - "9000"

networks:
  general-nt:
    external: true
```

I want to make this file as below with bash script.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app-php-fpm:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ${src}/
    volumes:
        - $path:path
    networks:
      general-nt:
        aliases:
        - app
    expose:
        - "9000"

  # ap2-php-fpm:
  #   container_name: app
  #   build:
  #     context: ${src}/
  #   volumes:
  #       - $path:path
  #   networks:
  #     general-nt:
  #       aliases:
  #       - app
  #   expose:
  #       - "9000"

networks:
  general-nt:
    external: true
```

Comment: A lot of duplicates in this forum,  but here `printf '%s\n' '/ap2-php-fpm:/;/^$/-1s/^/# /' %p Q | ed -s file.txt` change `Q` to `w` if in-place editing is needed.

Comment: Is it enough for your users to `docker-compose up app-php-fpm`, and only specify the services they do want to run?

Comment: Conversely, if you have old and new versions simultaneously, can they be allocated different ports?  This might also be convenient for cutting over live traffic if v2 is successful.

Comment: @DavidMaze it is another approach that i ll use if i cany do what i want. My bash script generates commands. With a lot of project that command lenght ll be huge

Comment: @DavidMaze it is not my questions answers but i decided to solve with your way. I was reading projects service name from a config file. I added a new value to check if it is wanted to deploy. Can you post your answer? I ll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many practical purposes, it may be enough to run `docker-compose up` with specific service names.  If you run

```sh
docker-compose up -d app-php-fpm
```

it will start the service(s) on the command line, and anything it `depends_on:`, but not anything else.  That would avoid the need to comment out parts of the YAML file.  You could otherwise interact with the containers normally.